# Publishing message from AWS Lambda to AWS IoT

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mqtt, aws-iot

I am trying to publish message from AWS Lamba using Nodejs to AWS IoT .
I have zipped the project and uploaded on to the AWS IoT
below is the code snippet

```
 var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');

 var device = awsIot.device({
  keyPath: 'keyfilepath',
  certPath: 'pem file path',
  caPath: 'root-CA.crt',
  clientId: 'iotTest7526532135',
  host: 'host id'
 });


device
  .on('connect', function() {
     console.log('connect');
     device.subscribe('topic_3');

     device.publish('topic_1', JSON.stringify({ message_id:23,Message:'HelloWorld'}));
    });

     device
     .on('message', function(topic, payload) {
console.log('message', topic, payload.toString());
 });
```

I am getting below error
"errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'aws-iot-device-sdk'",

I know that iot sdk is missing, I am not sure how to install it on AWS Lambda.

Any suggestions will be really helpful

Answer (score 19):

I would highly recommend not using the aws-iot-device-sdk to interact with AWS Iot from a Lambda function.

You need to understand there are 2 javascript APIs that you can use to access AWS IoT

- The [AWS IOT Device SDKs for javascript](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js), using MQTT as a protocol and x509 certificates for authentication. These are typically used in devices running outside of your AWS cloud.
- The [AWS SDK for javascript](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/), using HTTP as a protocol, and IAM roles (among other things) for authentication. These SDKs are typically run inside your AWS cloud (such as a Lambda)

There are multiple reasons why you should opt for the HTTP based SDK :

- The aws-iot-device-sdk is specifically targeted toward devices "living" outside of Aws (IoT gateways / devices in the field) that need to remotely connect.
- The Device SDK uses MQTT and x509 certificates to interact with AWS IoT. There is no need to configure x509 securities in your lambda. A Lambda running on your AWS account can easily access AWS IoT through an IAM role, so if your lambda function is configured with the correct role, you can use the standard aws sdks.
- A protocol like MQTT (or any pub/sub protocol) doesn't match well with a serverless lambda architecture. In your lambda function you are subscribing to a topic, something that you don't typically do in a short-lived lambda function.
- The AWS SDK for NodeJS is provided to your lambda out of the box.There's no need to require or package additional node modules)

Your code can become as simple as this (notice that there are no credentials or extra node modules required) :

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var iotdata = new AWS.IotData({endpoint:"yourendpoint.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"});

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

console.log("found iotdata",iotdata);

    var params = {
        topic: 'topic/test',
        payload: 'blah',
        qos: 0
        };


    iotdata.publish(params, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log("Error occured : ",err);
        }
        else{
            console.log("success.....");
        }
    });

    callback();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your good info, I've got a clear direction where to go now.

Answer (score 2):

When you zip your project, you also zip `./node_modules` folder. So as long as `aws-iot-device-sdk` is there (along with all the dependencies), your Lambda will be fine.

So all you need is:

```
npm install aws-iot-device-sdk
zip ...
```

Comment: Than you very much for the response , I ran the install command and the i ran  zip -r test_package.zip but there are no ./node_modules folder or file in the zip

Comment: I Made the changes and added the package.json in the zip file but still i am getting same error when i upload the zip on lambda

Comment: It Worked as per your instructions. My Bad :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to make sure you're uploading your `package.json` file as well, which should have a dependency requirement for `aws-iot-device-sdk`

you can add the package to your package.json by running

`npm -i --save aws-iot-device-sdk`

from your project directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just going to publish the data to IoT topic, you are better of using http protocol instead of MQTT connection.

And using HTTP connection doesnt require aws-iot-device-sdk package. AWS default SDK has iotdata. And iotdata will provide the http connection to the device.

iotHTTPConnection= AWS.IotData({endpoint: Your_END_POINT});

iotHTTPConnection.publish(params) will publish the data using http without iot specific sdk.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_iotdata_Publish.html

There is no http subscribe though.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like the below in your package.json file. then run `npm install`. This will create a node_modules folder. Now zip it and upload it once again.

```
"aws-iot-device-sdk": "^2.1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a good practice adding iot-sdk library into your Lambda function. Thats also the reason it doesn't come pre-installed into the Lambda services. It is clearly a library to connect devices to AWS cloud.

In your case as they mentioned above, the pre-installed aws-sdk is all you need.
Though you can't subscribe to a topic for the reason that the protocol to publish a message is HTTP.
But usually isn't a reason for that too.