# Use IotDataPlaneClient to publish to topic from within an AWS C++ lambda function

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I have written an AWS Lambda function in C++ which needs to publish to an IOT topic via HTTP.

The C++ function works when ran locally. But it fails when ran from the Lambda environment.

I read this thread: [Publishing message from AWS Lambda to AWS IoT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46723699/publishing-message-from-aws-lambda-to-aws-iot), which seems to describe what I would like to do.

The C++ code:

```
options.loggingOptions.logLevel = Aws::Utils::Logging::LogLevel::Trace;
options.loggingOptions.logger_create_fn = GetConsoleLoggerFactory();
Aws::InitAPI(options);

Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration conf;
//conf.connectTimeoutMs = 30000;
//conf.endpointOverride = "xxxx.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com";
Aws::IoTDataPlane::IoTDataPlaneClient client(conf);
Aws::IoTDataPlane::Model::PublishRequest request;
std::shared_ptr<Aws::StringStream> stream = std::make_shared<Aws::StringStream>("Something2 to publish.");

request.SetBody(stream);
request.SetTopic("MyTopic2");

Aws::IoTDataPlane::Model::PublishOutcome outcome(client.Publish(request));
if(outcome.IsSuccess())
{
    printf("Success");
}
else
{
    printf("%s", outcome.GetError().GetMessage().c_str());
}
Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);
```

The Lambda function logs show:

```
"....
    2020-11-16T01:17:12.559+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:12.559 CurlHandleContainer [140665310484032] Attempting to acquire curl connection.

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:12.559 CurlHandleContainer [140665310484032] No current connections available in pool. Attempting to create new connections.

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:12.559 CurlHandleContainer [140665310484032] attempting to grow pool size by 2

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [INFO] 2020-11-16 00:17:12.559 CurlHandleContainer [140665310484032] Pool grown by 2

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [INFO] 2020-11-16 00:17:12.559 CurlHandleContainer [140665310484032] Connection has been released. Continuing.

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:12.559 CurlHandleContainer [140665310484032] Returning connection handle 0x555555f758c0

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:12.559 CurlHttpClient [140665310484032] Obtained connection handle 0x555555f758c0

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:12.619 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) Trying 52.58.211.191:443...

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:12.619 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) TCP_NODELAY set

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.090 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) After 470ms connect time, move on!

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.090 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) connect to 52.58.211.191 port 443 failed: Connection timed out

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.090 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) Trying 35.156.92.155:443...

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.090 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) TCP_NODELAY set

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.325 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) After 234ms connect time, move on!

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.325 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) connect to 35.156.92.155 port 443 failed: Connection timed out

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.325 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) Trying 18.158.210.208:443...

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.325 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) TCP_NODELAY set

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.442 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) After 117ms connect time, move on!

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.442 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) connect to 18.158.210.208 port 443 failed: Connection timed out

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.442 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) Trying 3.120.61.10:443...

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.442 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) TCP_NODELAY set

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.500 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) After 58ms connect time, move on!

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.500 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) connect to 3.120.61.10 port 443 failed: Connection timed out

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.500 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) Trying 18.195.69.218:443...

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.500 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) TCP_NODELAY set

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.530 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) After 29ms connect time, move on!

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.530 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) connect to 18.195.69.218 port 443 failed: Connection timed out

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.530 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) Trying 18.196.9.115:443...

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.530 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) TCP_NODELAY set

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.544 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) After 14ms connect time, move on!

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.544 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) connect to 18.196.9.115 port 443 failed: Connection timed out

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.544 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) Trying 3.127.140.59:443...

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.544 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) TCP_NODELAY set

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.551 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) After 7ms connect time, move on!

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.551 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) connect to 3.127.140.59 port 443 failed: Connection timed out

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.551 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) Trying 52.57.218.228:443...

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.551 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) TCP_NODELAY set

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.555 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) After 3ms connect time, move on!

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.555 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) connect to 52.57.218.228 port 443 failed: Connection timed out

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.555 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) Failed to connect to data.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com port 443: Connection timed out

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.555 CURL [140665310484032] (Text) Closing connection 0

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [ERROR] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.555 CurlHttpClient [140665310484032] Curl returned error code 7 - Couldn't connect to server

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.555 CurlHandleContainer [140665310484032] Destroy curl handle: 0x555555f758c0

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.555 CurlHandleContainer [140665310484032] Created replacement handle and released to pool: 0x555555f758c0

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [DEBUG] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.555 AWSClient [140665310484032] Request returned error. Attempting to generate appropriate error codes from response

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   [ERROR] 2020-11-16 00:17:13.555 AWSClient [140665310484032] HTTP response code: -1

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   Resolved remote host IP address:

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   Request ID:

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   Exception name:

2020-11-16T01:17:13.555+01:00   Error message: curlCode: 7, Couldn't connect to server
..."
```

The role of the Lambda function

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iot:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can login in to an EC2 instance on the same VPC and do:

```
wget https://data.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
--2020-11-16 00:22:36--  https://data.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/
Resolving data.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com (data.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com)... 18.184.58.66, 18.194.185.52, 35.158.218.97, ...
Connecting to data.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com (data.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com)|18.184.58.66|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2020-11-16 00:22:36 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

So it seems the connection to the endpoint can be made.

There are no outbound security group restrictions.

I also have tried to increase conf.connectTimeoutMs to 30s. Indeed I see it takes longer to timeout. But still no connection.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Lambda function could not reach any public internet address due to faulty VPC configuration.

In the end I did this:

1. Create VCP
2. Create a subnet named "private"
3. Create a subnet named "public"
4. Create a internet gateway, associate with "public"
5. Create a NAT gateway, associate with "public"
6. Add a routing table for private and public
7. Private routing table: forward 0.0.0.0/0 to NAT gateway
8. Public routing table forward  0.0.0.0/0 to internet gateway
9. Associate the lambda function with the "private" subnet